# Missing Action Bar icons in a tabbed PageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I'm writing an Android app based on a MainActivity with several attached Fragments. The ActionBar displays navigation tabs, along with icons. Each fragment has a set of icons associated with it; MainActivity has a 'Close' icon which is also displayed. I display them by calling setHasOptionsMenu(true), and inflating the menu xml in onCreateOptionsMenu.
Menu XML example:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/apply"
    android:orderInCategory="50"

    android:title="@string/apply"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:orderInCategory="75"

    android:title="@string/reset"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>



</menu>
```

Right now, sometimes the icons display correctly, and other times the action bar appears to be missing icons. The missing icons don't appear in the overflow (I have a physical menu button) either. I've tried hiding all menus except the one belonging to the active fragment in PageView.setOnPageChangeListener, but that hasn't helped.

Thanks!

Comment: In the given example of menu .xml above, I don't see any `android:icon`. I wonder that might be the cause.

Comment: Whenever it does work, the default icon seems to be the item name in all caps (e.g. "UPDATE").

Answer (score 0):

Remove `app:showAsAction=...` attributes and delete the `app` namespace from the menu xml file.

Comment: Hi zaventh, I tried your suggestion, but still frequently see the icons vanish. What is removing the app and app:...attributes supposed to do?